# useEffect lazy created cleanup function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create hook that is is using an effect in which side effect function returns the cleanup callback. However I want to call it only when component is unmounted, not on the rerender.

Normal approach when you call useEffect with empty deps array won't work here as the cleanup function is created only once, on the first call of the hook. But my clean up is created later, so there is no way to change it.

```
function useListener(data) {
  const [response, updateResponse] = useState(null);

  useEffect(
    () => {
      if (data) {
        const removeListener = callRequest(data, resp => {
          updateResponse(resp);
        });

        return removeListener;
      }
    },
    [data]
  );

  return response;
}
```

This comes down to a following problem: In normal class component, the `willComponentUnmount` could make a decision based on a current component state but in case of useEffect, state is passed via closure to the cleanup and there is no way to pass the information later if the state has changed

Comment: `useEffect` defines a way to make your component reacts to a state/props change. Instead of thinking in terms of lifecycles, it's better with hooks to think about what state could lead to running an effect. At least, that's what React thoughtleaders like Dan Abramov or Ryan Florence keep saying :)

Comment: Yes, I know, although I really need to do a once off cleanup based on the state and I can’t think of a way to do it

Comment: What cause the unmounting of the component ? Only the fact that `data` is not `undefined` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `useRef` to save and update your callback function

> The useRef() Hook isn’t just for DOM refs. The “ref” object is a generic container whose current property is mutable and can hold any value, similar to an instance property on a class. [more](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables)

```
function useListener(data) {
  const [response, updateResponse] = useState(null);
  const cleanUpCallbackRef = useRef(() => {});

  useEffect(
    () => {
      if (data) {
        cleanUpCallbackRef.current = callRequest(data, resp => {
          updateResponse(resp);
        });
      }
    },
    [data]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      cleanUpCallbackRef.current();
    }
  }, []);
  return response;
}
```

I create a simple example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/24nkr885kp?from-embed)

Comment: thanks! This looks like exactly what I needed. I haven't thought of useRef, as I thought about it in context of DOM